# Unable to unregisterListener while using accelerometer during incoming calls

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, accelerometer

I have created a simple broadcast receiver to capture the accelerometer movement while the device receives. The motive of the app is turning the device over will mute incoming calls. Please check [this](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportOwnersHowToGuidePopup.do?howto_guide_seq=10140&prd_ia_cd=N0000003&map_seq=120549) (last point under motions heading). The app is working okay, but I want to unregisterListener when the broadcast receiver detects the idle mode. When I try to do that, I am getting this error:

```
05-27 13:01:21.122: E/MyApp(9836): Vibrate mode
05-27 13:01:25.426: E/Detecting(9836): PhoneIdle
05-27 13:01:25.436: E/actualRingerMode(9836): Actual State: Vibrate mode
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.abhideep.silentfacedown.IncommingCallReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2495)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at com.abhideep.silentfacedown.IncommingCallReceiver.onReceive(IncommingCallReceiver.java:83)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2488)
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836):     ... 10 more
```

The **broadcast receiver**:

```
public class IncommingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements
        SensorEventListener {

    static boolean ring = false;
    static boolean callReceived = false;

    SensorManager sensorManager;

    Context con;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
        con = mContext;
        // Get the current Phone State
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state == null)
            return;

        // If phone state "Rininging"
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            ring = true;

            Log.d("Detecting", "PhoneRing");
            // create instance of sensor manager and get system service to
            // interact with Sensor

            AudioManager am;
            am = (AudioManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                Log.e("MyApp", "Silent mode");
                saveInPreference("actualRingerModeset", "Silent mode");
                Log.i("actualRingerModeset", "Silent mode");
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                Log.e("MyApp", "Vibrate mode");
                saveInPreference("actualRingerModeset", "Vibrate mode");
                Log.i("actualRingerModeset", "Vibrate mode");
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                Log.e("MyApp", "Normal mode");
                saveInPreference("actualRingerModeset", "Normal mode");
                Log.i("actualRingerModeset", "Normal mode");
                break;
            }

            sensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                    sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        }

        // If incoming call is received
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            callReceived = true;
        }

        // If phone is Idle
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.e("Detecting", "PhoneIdle");
            Log.e("actualRingerMode", "Actual State: "
                    + getFromPreference("actualRingerModeset"));
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            reactivatePhone(con, getFromPreference("actualRingerModeset"));
            // sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            // If phone was ringing(ring=true) and not
            // received(callReceived=false) , then it is a missed call
            if (ring == true && callReceived == false) {
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // check sensor type
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            // assign directions
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];


            // Log.d("Log X:", ""+x);
            // Log.d("Log Y:", ""+y);
            // Log.d("Log Z:", "" + z);

            if (z < -4) {
                silentPhone(con);
            }

//          float[] g = new float[3]; 
//          g = event.values.clone();
//
//          double norm_Of_g = Math.sqrt(g[0] * g[0] + g[1] * g[1] + g[2] * g[2]);
//
//          // Normalize the accelerometer vector
//          g[0] = (float) (g[0] / norm_Of_g);
//          g[1] = (float) (g[1] / norm_Of_g);
//          g[2] = (float) (g[2] / norm_Of_g);
//          
//          int inclination = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(g[2])));
//          
//          if ( inclination > 155)
//          {
//              // device is flat
//              Log.e("Position", "not flat");
//              silentPhone(con);
//          }
//          else
//          {
//              // device is not flat
//              Log.e("Position", "flat");
//          }

        }
    }

    public void silentPhone(Context context) {
        AudioManager am;
        am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // For Silent mode
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    }

    public void reactivatePhone(Context context, String actualMode) {
        AudioManager am;
        am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Log.e("Tag", "Hello: " + actualMode);
        if (actualMode.equalsIgnoreCase("Normal mode")) {
            // For NORMAL mode
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }

        if (actualMode.equalsIgnoreCase("Silent mode")) {
            // For Silent mode
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }

        if (actualMode.equalsIgnoreCase("Vibrate mode")) {
            // For VIBRATE mode
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        }

    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // Preference Variable
    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    // --------------------------------------------
    // method to save variable in preference
    // --------------------------------------------
    public void saveInPreference(String name, String content) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(name, content);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------
    // getting content from preferences
    // --------------------------------------------
    public String getFromPreference(String variable_name) {
        String preference_return;
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
        preference_return = preferences.getString(variable_name, "");

        return preference_return;
    }

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // Preference Variable
    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the stacktrace tells you what is wrong:

```
05-27 13:01:25.446: E/AndroidRuntime(9836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.abhideep.silentfacedown.IncommingCallReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It says:

**Unable to start receiver** in **IncommingCallReceiver** where there is a **nullpointer** somewhere.

So to debug, go to the class HomeActivity and check every instance of every object for == null then throw your own exception and start from there.

Comment: i updated my answer, but it's the same basically :) you have to check for nullpointers and figure out which object is null.

Comment: This line sensorManager.unregisterListener(this); is creating the problem. I can not unregister the sensor.

Comment: Did you check if sensorManager is null?